# What affects my search results using Brave Search engine?

Tags: browser, search-engines

I am using Brave Browser and LibreWolf on the same computer and I have realized that I can get totally different results using Brave Search looking for the same thing.

For example I have been looking for some a possible reasons of a kernel panic on OpenBSD and this is what I have got using both browsers:
[image]
Since LibreWolf does not keep neither search history nor visited sites I prefer to use Brave for things that may be useful in the future. But as it is depicted on the attached screenshot Brave Browser returns way less results (and what is even worse those that I found useful appeared in LibreWolf).

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you like better the search engine that is used by LibreWolf,
just set Brave to use the same engine.

As LibreWolf is a clone of Firefox, the following article will probably
apply to it (perhaps with slight changes):
[Add or remove a search engine in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox).
LibreWolf prefers privacy-conscious search providers:
DuckDuckGo, Searx, Qwant and more.

Manipulating the search engine in Brave is described in
[Set Brave Search as default](https://search.brave.com/default).

Comment: I am using the same engine on both browsers. It just a search result that differs.

Comment: That's weird. Try to compare the search URL used by both browsers - perhaps some parameter is added or missing in Brave.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely based on the difference that [search engine] sees when you request this information. Lots of data is sent to the search engine such as the browser type/version, operating system/version, running session data other than site and search history (think cookies, geographical location). I highly suspect that this strongly affects the type of search results that are given- it has affected me, too.

Simply put, your r the way that the search engine decides to handle the data it receives from your browser when you search.

Spoiler: I don't own or operate a search engine.

Comment: I think you may be right. I've checked what results do I get in incognito mode in the Brave browser and it seems the results are the same as in LibreWolf. I guess a difference in cookies is the answer.